# QuickCheck Generator not terminating

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, quickcheck

This QuickCheck generator

```hs
notEqual :: Gen (Int, Int)
notEqual = do
  (a, b) <- arbitrary
  if a /= b
    then return (a, b)
    else notEqual
```

Doesn't seem to terminate when passed to `forAll`. I'm guessing the recursion is going into an infinite loop somehow, but why?

Comment: This seems to work correctly for me. However, a better way to do this would be to use `suchThat`: https://gist.github.com/asheshambasta/93b2211d2d2a42295f6e9436dd91c3c9

Comment: What's probably happening is that your tests are starting with the smallest size, which generates `(0,0)` for `Int`. I think the delta approach below is the bets solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `suchThat` combinator that @Ashesh and @Carsten pointed out is definitely what I am looking for, to succinctly and idiomatically generate a non-equal pair.

An explanation for the infinite recursion (Thanks to @oisdk):

All QuckCheck runners (`quickCheck`, `forAll` etc.) pass a [*size parameter*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#15) to test genarators. This has no defined semantics, but early tests use a small parameter, starting at 0*, and gradually growing. Generators use this to generate samples of different 'sizes,' whatever that may mean for a specific datatype.

`arbitrary` for integral types (called recursively by `arbitrary` for `(Int, Int)`), uses this for the magnitude of the generated value - *generate an integral between 0 and `size`*.

This means, unfortunately, that the *first test* attempted by `quickCheck`, (or in my case `forAll`,) uses the size 0, which *can only generate `(0, 0)`*. This always fails the test of `/=`, causing the action to recurse infinitely, looking for more.

* I'm assuming this, as the behaviour of the size parameter doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in doubt of termination/finding results you can always try to circumvent this:

```hs
notEqual' :: Gen (Int, Int)
notEqual' = do
  start <- arbitrary
  delta <- oneof [pos, neg]
  pure (start, start + delta)
  where
      pos = getPositive <$> arbitrary
      neg = getNegative <$> arbitrary
```

Of course internally both `Postitive` and `Negative` use `suchThat` so as Ashesh mentioned

```hs
notEqual :: Gen (Int, Int)
notEqual = genPair `suchThat` uncurry (/=)
  where genPair = arbitrary
```

might be easier